# How to bind a command to a button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to wpf and this fancy binding stuff, followed these [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/238657/How-to-use-Commands-in-WPF) and got this `XAML`:

```
<Button
    x:Name="btn"
    Content="refresh"
    Command="{Binding RefreshCmd}" />
```

and this code:

```
public someClass ()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    CreateRefreshCmd();
    btn.DataContext=this; // without this line it will not work !!
}

public ICommand RefreshCmd
{
    get;
     internal set;
}

private bool CanExecuteRefreshCmd ()
{
    return true;
}

private void CreateRefreshCmd ()
{
    RefreshCmd=new RelayCommand(e => RefreshExec(), c => this.CanExecuteRefreshCmd());
}

public void RefreshExec ()
{
    // do something fancy here !
}
```

but without the last line in constructor it will not work.

In the tutorial this line does not exist.

How can i avoid this?

EDIT:

I clicked the databinding with visual studio and got this:

```
Command="{Binding RefreshCmd, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type my:spielerei}}}"
```

is this really necessary?

Comment: The datacontext might be set in the xaml of the view in your tutorial.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For binding to work, you need to set a data context for bindings to target, so yes, it is necessary. In the `Command` binding you posted in your edit, the binding is instructed to look for the `RefreshCmd` property on an ancestor of the `Button` control of type `my:spielerei`, which I assume is the containing window type. This is why the explicit setting of `DataContext` doesn't appear in the tutorial.

Bindings and commands can be used in code-behind, but are much more commonly used with view-models in the MVVM pattern. This involves setting the `DataContext` of your class to a view-model, which contains the properties and commands you want to bind to. To change your code to follow MVVM, we need a view-model:

```
public class SomeClassViewModel
{
    public SomeClassViewModel()
    {
        this.RefreshCmd = new RelayCommand(e => RefreshExec(), c => this.CanExecuteRefreshCmd());
    }

    public ICommand RefreshCmd { get; internal set; }

    private bool CanExecuteRefreshCmd()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void RefreshExec()
    {
        // do something fancy here !
    }
}
```

Then, in the code-behind, create the view-model, and assign it as the data context of the object:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public SomeClass()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new SomeClassViewModel();
    }
}
```

Notice that all of the code from the `SomeClass` code-behind file has moved to the view-model - it is now testable, and your XAML controls can communicate with the view-model by binding to properties and executing commands.

Comment: thank you, very nice explanation. code is worth a thousand words!! i have to initialize these MVVM stuff during next days!

Answer (score 0):

Binding will work correctly if there is an object it can bind to. This object is read from *DataContext* property. If this property is not set there is nothing to bind to. It is why the following line is needed:

```
btn.DataContext=this;
```

The tutorial mentioned by you does it in a little bit different way i.e. it sets *DataContext* in XAML. Please examine *MainWindow.xaml* file from this tutorial. It contains the following code at the beginning which populates *DataContext* property:

```
<Window x:Class="MvvmCommand.MainWindow" DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
```

Comment: i did not downloaded the tutorial code.. sorry. thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

When you use a Binding in WPF, by default it sets the binding to the named property on the DataContext of the object that has the property that is bound.  So in your example, the DataContext of the button.
This property is inherited down through the tree, so if not set on the Button it will look up the tree all the way to the window that holds the control.

[MSDN on binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Without all your XAML to look through I do have to guess, but I am guessing you haven't set the datacontext of the window that hosts the button.  By setting it in the constructor explicitly to this you are setting the source of the binding to the object that has the property, hence why it works.

The normal way to do this is to set the data context to a class that contains the command.  The usual design pattern for this is MVVM.  The idea of binding is to have separation - it is not like events where you handle them in the code behind, instead it allows you to create a view model or similar class that exposes the commands and bind this to the view.  This allows you to do things like unit test the functionality via the view model without having to unit test the view, share view models to multiple views etc.

Answer (score 0):

data context is required to be set so that binding framework can resolve the values

you may have various method of setting the same

first method you've used

another method is to set via xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Project.MainWindow"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

Idea here is to set the data context to self.

Answer (score 0):

In short, It's not necessary. Do not set datacontext to button, set data context (viemodel) for your page (view) in XAML. Of course your command must be exposed via that viewmodel.

For another question I put up simple example showing command binding and cross viewmodel communication, check it out here https://github.com/mikkoviitala/cross-viewmodel-communication